# GKTurnBasedMatch handleMatchEnded: not called

Tags: ios6, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm programming a simple 2 players board game with *GameKit* and the *GKTurnBased* API, my problem is at the end of my game, when I want to detect that a player won and another lost.

First at all, the **handleTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:** method fired, in this method, I check the other participant status:

```
// Test other players status
    for(GKTurnBasedParticipant *participant in match.participants)
    {
        if([participant.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID])
            continue;

        if(participant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit || participant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost)
        {
            [self findMeInMatch:match].matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
            [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:match.matchData
                             completionHandler:nil];
            return;
        }
        else if(participant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon)
        {
            [self findMeInMatch:match].matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
            [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:match.matchData
                             completionHandler:nil];
            return;
        }
        else if(participant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied)
        {
            [self findMeInMatch:match].matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
            [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:match.matchData
                             completionHandler:nil];
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // OK
        }
    }
[...]
```

My problem now is that the **handleMatchEnded:** method is never called... The weird thing is that this method is part of the same delegate protocol as **handleTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:** which actually works.

Any idea is welcome.

Cheers.

**UPDATE 03/17:**
As my first player quitted is turn, and the second one end the match, I think the two players are not going to receive the event. This event is probably made for other players in game, or when players are not within the app when the others leave. Didn't find anything related in the documentation, but it seem's logical.

Cyril